# Adding events after the page render React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have a situation when SVG loaded from the server after the page render and after that, I need to add certain events to its elements. Let's say after clicking on a rect it shows an alert.

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import css from "./room-plan.module.css";
import { Button } from "../../components";

export default function RoomPlan({ svg }) {

  useEffect(() => {
    var elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('svg rect'));

    elements.forEach(function(el) {
      el.addEventListener("click", alert("hello"));
   })
  }, [])

  
  return (
      <div>
        <h2 className={css.labels}>Select desk</h2>
          <div id={css.roomPlan} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: svg, }}></div>
        <div className={css.bookingButtons}>
          <Button>CANCEL</Button>
          <Button>BOOK DESK</Button>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

But it totally does not work. Just does not add any events on elements. Cuz when it looks for the required selector it does not exist yet.

Comment: you could possibly try `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect` since it runs after the DOM has been set up

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct, but make sure to include a [return function inside the useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1)  for cleanup during component unmount

```html
useEffect(() => {
    var elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('svg rect'));
    const listener = () => alert("hello");
    
    if(elements) {
       elements.forEach(function(el) {
          el.addEventListener("click", listener);
       })
    }

     return function cleanup(){
        if(elements) {
           elements.forEach(function(el) {
              el.removeEventListener("click", listener);
            })
        }
     }
         
},[])
```